# Get specific points from matrix with one command

Tags: matlab, matrix

Supposing I have this matrix:

```
>> m = magic(4)

m =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
```

and I want do access these positions `x1 = [1;3]` and `x2 = [4;3]`, I mean, I want a result like this: `[13; 6]`, the `[x1(1); x2(1)]` and `[x1(2); x2(2)]` positions. `x1` and `x2` can have any size. I tried doing `m(x1, x2)`, but did not work... Is there a way to achieve this with one command?

Comment: `x = [m(1,3),m(4,3)] ` ?

Comment: sorry, edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get multiple values with linear indices, say in your case `m([13, 6]);`

To get linear indices, use `sub2ind(size(m), x1, x2);` which will generate [13,6] in your case.

Now just glue them together to get the one-liner:

```
out = m(sub2ind(size(m), x1, x2));
```

Comment: colons are redundant. you can remove them.

Comment: @OmG Thanks, fixed.